# How to t-sql datetime convert +1 day

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sap-ase, valueconverter

How to add +1 day to convert?

Statement :-

```
declare @dtend char (10)
select @dtend = '14.03.2014'

declare @sdtend datetime
select  @sdtend = convert( datetime, @dtend, 104)
```

Comment: is it sql server RDBMS?

Comment: Well, `mysql` doesn't run `T-SQL` so if the rest of the tagging is correct, the `mysql` tag isn't.

Comment: Syntax of OP's examples clearly tell that they are `t-sql` related but not `MySQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**T-SQL Solution**:
Use `DATEADD` function on the converted datetime value.

Try this:

```
select @sdtend = dateadd( day, 1, convert( datetime, @dtend, 104)
```

***Refer to***:

1. [CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ]
   )](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

   - Converts an expression of one data type to another.
2. [DATEADD (datepart , number , date )](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

   - Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed
     integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.